# Cannot copy text from Acrobat reader on Ubuntu

Tags: copy, paste, adobe-acrobat

I'm using Adobe Reader version 9.5.5 04/26/2013 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. I can select some text in Acrobat reader, I can use the menu Edit->Copy but when I paste in Gedit, nothing happens and nothing is copied. Is this a bug or is there a special setting somewhere?

Comment: open it with "document viewer"

Comment: Copy with Ctrl-C & Paste with Mouse3 (or shift-Ins)

Comment: Can you copy text from other PDF files? if so, the problem is related to protections applied on this particular PDF file

Comment: Sorry. The document was protected for copy indeed...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The file was protected for copy.